# THREE.JS : GLTFLoader 404 Not Found problem

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, http-status-code-404, gltf

I am trying to add a 3D model in my webpage with Three.js so I used a GLTFLoader, but I am facing an 404 Error when fetching the model, which I find weird because this is the correct path to the model. Here is the error I get in the console:

> Error: fetch for "http://127.0.0.1:5500/modele/voiture/scene.gltf" responded with 404: Not Found

In my js code I created a loadModel() function that I added in my init() function. This is the loadModel() function:

```js
function loadModel() {
    // ------------ loader d'image 3D -------------- //
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    //loader.setCrossOrigin('./');
    
    loader.load('modele/voiture/scene.gltf', function(gltf){ 
        var voiture = gltf.scene;
        voiture.scale.setScalar(5);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        voiture = gltf.scene.children[0];
        rendu.render(scene, camera);
    });
}
```

Any advice on my code is very welcome :D Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a "/" before the url.

```
function loadModel() {
    // ------------ loader d'image 3D -------------- //
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    //loader.setCrossOrigin('./');
    
    loader.load('/modele/voiture/scene.gltf', function(gltf){ 
        var voiture = gltf.scene;
        voiture.scale.setScalar(5);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        voiture = gltf.scene.children[0];
        rendu.render(scene, camera);
    });
}
```

Or use the complete link:

```
function loadModel() {
    // ------------ loader d'image 3D -------------- //
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    //loader.setCrossOrigin('./');
    
    loader.load("http://127.0.0.1:5500/modele/voiture/scene.gltf", function(gltf){ 
        var voiture = gltf.scene;
        voiture.scale.setScalar(5);
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        voiture = gltf.scene.children[0];
        rendu.render(scene, camera);
    });
}
```

And if it does not work try running
`curl "http://127.0.0.1:5500/modele/voiture/scene.gltf"`in your terminal. If it does not get something, there is something wrong with the server or the url.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! When I add the '/' in the path I don't get anything different than without. When I type 'curl "http://127.0.0.1:5500/modele/voiture/scene.gltf" ' in the console I get an Uncaught syntax error: unexpected token: string literal (when I type the quote) and identifier (when I try without quotes).

Finally I have a Cross Origin Error when I type the entire url in the code (will it be a problem when uploading the code to the website?)

Comment: `curl` was to be executed in the OS shell, like cmd or terminal.
Anyway I think it is the server that is not sending the file for some reason. And the code you provided here is okay. 
So maybe you have to do "Allow CORS" in the server.

Comment: If I allow CORS locally on my development server, will it still be the case on the webserver where I will upload my code? I'm afraid it won't and that the model wouldn't be loaded when the model will be online...

Comment: helped me out a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by putting the glb file in the public folder in React Project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).